# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException

Tags: java

I have to read xls file in java.I used poi-3.6 to read xls file in Eclipse.But i m getting this ERROR"**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException at ReadExcel2.main(ReadExcel2.java:38)**".

I have added following jars 
1)poi-3.6-20091214.jar
2)poi-contrib-3.6-20091214.jar
3)poi-examples-3.6-20091214.jar
4)poi-ooxml-3.6-20091214.jar
5)poi-ooxml-schemas-3.6-20091214.jar
6)poi-scratchpad-3.6-20091214.jar

Below is the code which i m using:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ReadExcel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //
        // An excel file name. You can create a file name with a full path
        // information.
        //
        String filename = "C:\\myExcel.xl";
        //
        // Create an ArrayList to store the data read from excel sheet.
        //
        List sheetData = new ArrayList();

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            //
            // Create a FileInputStream that will be use to read the excel file.
            //
            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

            //
            // Create an excel workbook from the file system.
            //
           // HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);  

            //
            // Get the first sheet on the workbook.
            //
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //
            // When we have a sheet object in hand we can iterator on each
            // sheet's rows and on each row's cells. We store the data read
            // on an ArrayList so that we can printed the content of the excel
            // to the console.
            //
            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                Row row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

                List data = new ArrayList();
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                    data.add(cell);
                }

                sheetData.add(data);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }

        showExelData(sheetData);
    }
    private static void showExelData(List sheetData) {
        //
        // Iterates the data and print it out to the console.
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
            List list = (List) sheetData.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                Cell cell = (XSSFCell) list.get(j);
                System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                if (j < list.size() - 1) {
                    System.out.print(", ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.
thanks in anticipation,
Regards,
Dheeraj!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need [xmlbeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) on your classpath.

[`NoClassDefFoundError`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) means that:

> The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

So next time you get an exception like this, it means that some 3rd party library requires another 3rd party library. Then use google (or any other means) to find which library this is.
Furthermore, most libraries state clearly in their documentations and/or distributions what are their dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

[JarFinder](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException) suggests XMLBeans.jar

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error on Apache POI 3.16. Added the following jars from Apache POI /ooxml-lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0 and for the next exception regarding collections /lib/commons-collections4-4.1.jar to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation in linux env, basically my lib path level was off by 1.